How do I get mouse coordinates relative to my sf::View?
I'm using displaying a sf::RenderTexture in an ImGui::Image and I'm trying to get the mouse coordinates relative to it.
Here is my code:
    if (ImGui::Begin("Viewport", nullptr, GetFlags()))
    {
        mRenderTexture.clear(mClearColor);

        if (!mRenderTexture.create(800, 600))
        {
            spdlog::error("Failed to create render texture");
            return;
        }

        mView.reset(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, mRenderTexture.getSize().x, mRenderTexture.getSize().y));

        mRenderTexture.setView(mView);

        auto mousePos = mRenderTexture.mapCoordsToPixel(ImGui::GetMousePos);
        spdlog::info("Mouse pos: ({}, {})", mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

        mRenderTexture.display();

        ImGui::Image(mRenderTexture);
    }


I'm trying to get the top-left corner of the viewport to correspond to 0,0 but even if I use the mapCoordsToPixel function, it still gives the coordinates relative to the window rather than the view that the RenderTexture is using. What do I need to do to convert it to the view coordinates?
I've tried many solutions from SFML forums and it still doesn't work.

You can capture the top-left coordinate of the image in window coordinates by calling
ImVec2 offset = GetCursorPos();

right before you call ImGui::Image(mRenderTexture).
If you subtract offset from sf::Mouse.getPosition(currentWindow) you should get what you want.
